# Const-correctness in matrix example

Tags: c++, constants

I have a matrix class that use `std::vector` of `std::vector`'s inside.
I want to allow using `matrix[i][j]` syntax but not explode std::vector in interface so I have created a Row class.

```
template <typename T>
class Row {
public:
    explicit Row(std::vector<T>& value): value(value) {

    }

    T& operator [] (size_t index) {
        return value[index];
    }

private:
    std::vector<T>& value;
};

template <typename T>
class Matrix {
public:
    Matrix(std::size_t n, std::size_t m, const T& value = T()): value(n, std::vector<T>(m, value)) {

    }

    // irrelevant functions

    Row<T> operator [] (size_t index) {
        return Row(value[index]);
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> value;
};
```

Everything is fine until I want to work with const Matrix. If I have a const Matrix, I can't create `Row` because I only have `const operator []` of outer vector (and so only `const vector<T>&`) and if I change `Row` ctor argument to `const vector<T>&` I'll not be able to return T&.

I know I can create a class ConstRow that will have absolutely same functionality except that it'll get/return const refs but is it possible to workaround this nicely without creating a new class?

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid the overhead of having to maintain a class by using:

```
template <typename T>
using Row = std::vector<T>;
```

and using `Row` in the definition of `Matrix`.

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix {
public:
    Matrix(std::size_t n, std::size_t m, const T& value = T()): value(n, Row<T>(m, value)) {

    }

    // irrelevant functions

    Row<T>& operator [] (size_t index) {
        return value[index];
    }

    Row<T> const& operator [] (size_t index) const {
        return value[index];
    }

private:
    std::vector<Row<T>> value;
};
```

The proper way of dealing with `const`-ness of `Row` is automatically taken care of.

Comment: @Jarod42, Great eyes. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

> I know I can create a class ConstRow that will have absolutely same functionality except that it'll get/return const refs but is it possible to workaround this nicely without creating a new class

There's no workaround; that's your only option (or at least the only option that's not more trouble than it's worth).  Consider that even the standard library containers, like `list`, use different types for iterators over const lists and non-const lists.

Comment: That sounds like an argument :(

Answer (score 0):

Write an array view class.  It takes a type `T` and exposes `T*` iterstors via `T* begin() const` and `T* end() const`.  It has an `T& operator[](size_t)const` that lets you do random access.  And `size`, `front`, `back`, `empty` while you are st it.

For ctors, it has pointer-and-pointer, pointer-and-size, C array, `std::array<T,N>` snd `std::vector<T,A>&`.  `non_const_T` variants with `const&` can be added with some work.

Now your `[]` returns an `array_view<T>`, whike `[] const` returns `array_view<const T>`, and bob is your uncle.

Adding stride to it is also an option.  But I would not bother.

Comment: It is the factorisation of `Row` and `ConstRow` via template.

Comment: @jarod42 sort of, except it is surprisingly useful elsewhere.